# Asp.Net Framework MVC 5 - How to prevent the entire View from being reloaded when uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KapmO.png)
[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeZPT.png)
I'm trying to update only in Modal (Bootstrap) with the list of files I just uploaded. I am returning a partial view in Json.
The problem is that
the entire View is reloaded when the file upload is complete and the json return overwrites the page.

I tried to use ajax to update only part of the page but the controller does not understand how to send the IEnumerable HttpPostedFileBase.

Would anyone know an easy way and load only the result of UploadQuerys in modal?

**_UploadQuerys.cshtml**

```
@model Packer_v2.Models.PackageViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadQuerys", "Package", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="well">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>Arquivo : </td>
                <td><input type="file" id="File" name="File" multiple /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit"  id="Files" value="Enviar Arquivo" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@ViewBag.Mensagem</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
}
```

**Class PackageViewModel**

```
     public class PackageViewModel
        {
    
            public int IdEps { get; set; }
            public int? IdProject { get; set; }
            public int? IdSolution { get; set; }
            public int? IdDtbase { get; set; }
            public bool HasSqlScripts { get; set; }
            public int? IdSqlComandType { get; set; }
    
            public int? IdSqlItenType { get; set; }
    
            public int? IdQuery { get; set; }
    
            public Query Query { get; set; }
    
            public UploadFileResult File { get; set; }
    
            public List<Query> Querys { get; set; }
    
            //public List<ScriptType> ScriptType { get { return GetScriptTypes(); } }
            public List<Eps> EpsList { get; set; }
            public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
            public List<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }
            public List<Dtbase> Dtbases { get; set; }
    
    
            public List<SqlComandType> GetSqlComandTypes()
            {
                List<SqlComandType> _List = new List<SqlComandType>();
    
                _List.Add(new SqlComandType() { IdSqlComandType = 1, NmSqlComandType = "Update" });
                _List.Add(new SqlComandType() { IdSqlComandType = 2, NmSqlComandType = "Drop" });
                _List.Add(new SqlComandType() { IdSqlComandType = 3, NmSqlComandType = "Alter" });
                _List.Add(new SqlComandType() { IdSqlComandType = 4, NmSqlComandType = "Create" });
    
                return _List;
            }
    
            public List<SqlItenType> GetSqlItenTypes()
            {
                List<SqlItenType> _List = new List<SqlItenType>();
    
                _List.Add(new SqlItenType() { IdSqlItenType = 1, NmSqlItenType = "Table" });
                _List.Add(new SqlItenType() { IdSqlItenType = 2, NmSqlItenType = "View" });
                _List.Add(new SqlItenType() { IdSqlItenType = 3, NmSqlItenType = "Procedure" });
                _List.Add(new SqlItenType() { IdSqlItenType = 4, NmSqlItenType = "Column" });
    
                return _List;
            }
    
        }
    
        public class SqlComandType
        {
            public int IdSqlComandType { get; set; }
            public string NmSqlComandType { get; set; }
    
        }
    
        public class SqlItenType
        {
            public int IdSqlItenType { get; set; }
            public string NmSqlItenType { get; set; }
    
        }
    
        public class UploadFileResult
        {
            public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> File { get; set; }
    
        }
```

**PackageController**

```
    public class PackageController : Controller
    {
        private PackerContext db = new PackerContext();

        private List<Query> AllQuerys;

        // GET: Eps
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var vm = this.GetPackage();
            return View("Index", vm);
        }

        private PackageViewModel GetPackage()
        {
            var vm = new PackageViewModel();
            vm.EpsList = db.Eps.ToList();
            vm.Projects = new List<Project>();
            vm.Solutions = new List<Solution>();
            vm.Dtbases = new List<Dtbase>();
            vm.Querys = new List<Query>();
            return vm;
        }

        public JsonResult GetProjectsByEps(int pIdEps)
        {
            var projects = db.Project.Where(x => x.idEps == pIdEps).ToList();
            var vm = new PackageViewModel();
            vm.Projects = projects;

            var partial = PartialView("_GetProjectsByEpsDropDownList", vm).RenderToString();

            return Json(new { status = "ok", partialView = partial }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult GetSolutionsByProject(int pIdProject)
        {
            var solutions = db.Solution.Where(x => x.IdProject == pIdProject).ToList();
            var vm = new PackageViewModel();
            vm.Solutions = solutions;

            var partial = PartialView("_GetSolutionsByProjectDropDownList", vm).RenderToString();

            return Json(new { status = "ok", partialView = partial }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult GetDatabasesBySolution(int pIdSolution)
        {
            var IdsSolutions = db.DbSolution.Where(x => x.IdSolution == pIdSolution).ToList();

            var _Dtbases = new List<Dtbase>();
            foreach (var s in IdsSolutions)
            {
                var inserir = db.Dtbase.Where(x => x.IdDtbase == s.IdDtbase).FirstOrDefault();
                _Dtbases.Add(inserir);
            }

            var vm = new PackageViewModel();
            vm.Dtbases = _Dtbases;

            var partial = PartialView("_GetDatabasesBySolutionDropDownList", vm).RenderToString();

            return Json(new { status = "ok", partialView = partial }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadQuerys(UploadFileResult _pFiles)
        {

            //AllQuerys = new List<Query>();
            List<Query> TemporaryQuerys = new List<Query>();
            try
            {
                string fileName = "";
                string sendingFiles = "";

                foreach (var file in _pFiles.File)
                {
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var Query = new Query();

                        fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var way = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Packages/Querys"), fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(way);

                        Query.IsActive = true;
                        Query.NmFile = fileName;

                        TemporaryQuerys.Add(Query);
                    }

                    sendingFiles = sendingFiles + " , " + fileName;
                }
                ViewBag.Mensagem = "Arquivos enviados  : " + sendingFiles + " , com sucesso.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Mensagem = "Erro : " + ex.Message;
            }


            var vm = new PackageViewModel();
            vm.Querys = TemporaryQuerys;

            var partial = PartialView("_GetQuerys", vm).RenderToString();

            return Json(new { status = "ok", partialView = partial }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@model Packer_v2.Models.PackageViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Insert Package";
}

<h2>Iniciando o PACOTE</h2>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>* EPS</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdEps, Model.EpsList.OrderBy(o => o.NmEps).Select(x => new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = x.IdEps.ToString(),
               Text = x.NmEps
           }), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>* Project</label>
                <div id="divGetProjectsByEps">
                    @Html.Partial("_GetProjectsByEpsDropDownList")
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>* Solution</label>
                <div id="divGetSolutionsByProject">
                    @Html.Partial("_GetSolutionsByProjectDropDownList")
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <label>Selecione os itens do seu Pacote:</label>
                <div>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.HasSqlScripts, new { @checked = "checked", @class = "form-check-input", @id = "HasSqlScripts" })
                    <label> Querys</label>
                </div>

                @*<div>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.HasSqlScripts, new { @checked = "checked", @class = "form-check-input", @id = "HasSqlScripts" })
                    <label> Itens de App</label>
                    </div>*@
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<label>* Solution</label>
            <div id="divItensPacker">
                @Html.Partial("_TicketCreate")
            </div>*@


        <div id="divHasSQL" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <label>Scripts SQL</label>
                    <div id="divGetDatabasesBySolution">
                        @Html.Partial("_GetDatabasesBySolutionDropDownList")
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*<div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>* Comando</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSqlComandType, Model.GetSqlComandTypes().OrderBy(o => o.NmSqlComandType).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = x.IdSqlComandType.ToString(),
                           Text = x.NmSqlComandType
                       }), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @value = "0" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>* Item Sql</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSqlItenType, Model.GetSqlItenTypes().OrderBy(o => o.NmSqlItenType).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = x.IdSqlItenType.ToString(),
                           Text = x.NmSqlItenType
                       }), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @value = "0" })
                        </div>
                    </div>*@

                @*<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.Partial("_UploadQuerys")
                        </div>
                    </div>*@

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Inserir Querys</button>

                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">




                                @*<label>* Comando</label>
                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSqlComandType, Model.GetSqlComandTypes().OrderBy(o => o.NmSqlComandType).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Value = x.IdSqlComandType.ToString(),
                                        Text = x.NmSqlComandType
                                    }), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @value = "0" })



                                         <label>* Item Sql</label>
                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSqlItenType, Model.GetSqlItenTypes().OrderBy(o => o.NmSqlItenType).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Value = x.IdSqlItenType.ToString(),
                                        Text = x.NmSqlItenType
                                    }), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @value = "0" })*@


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        @Html.Partial("_UploadQuerys")

                                        @*<table class="table table-striped">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Arquivo : </td>
                                                    <td><input type="file" id="File" name="File" multiple /></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="Files" value="Enviar Arquivo" /></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@ViewBag.Mensagem</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>*@



                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var form = $("#form");
        var registerForm = new RegisterForm(form);
        registerForm.urlSave = "/Package/SavePackage";
        registerForm.urlDelete = "/Package/DeletePackage"

        blockAllFields();

        /**/
        //$(document).ready(function () { }

        //    'click', '#Files', function () {
        //    getQuerys();
        //});

        /**/

        $(document).on('click', '#Files', function () {
            console.log("clicou");
            getQuerys();
        });

        /*Changes*/
        $(document).on('change', '#IdEps', function () {
            let idEps = $("#IdEps").val();
            getProjectsByEps(idEps);
            var select = false;
            if (idEps == "")
                select = true;
            controlerFields(select, 'IdProject');
        });

        $(document).on('change', '#IdProject', function () {
            let idProject = $("#IdProject").val();
            getSolutionsByProject(idProject);
            var select = false;
            if (idProject == "")
                select = true;
            controlerFields(select, 'IdSolution');
        });

        $(document).on('change', '#IdSolution', function () {
            let idSolution = $("#IdSolution").val();
            getDatabasesBySolution(idSolution);
            var select = false;
            if (idSolution == "")
                select = true;
            controlerFields(select, 'HasSqlScripts');
        });

        $("#HasSqlScripts").change(function () {
            let hasSqlScriptsCheck = $('#HasSqlScripts').is(':checked');
            showDivHasChecked(hasSqlScriptsCheck, 'divHasSQL');
            var select = false;
            if (hasSqlScriptsCheck == "")
                select = true;
            controlerFields(select, 'IdDtbase');
        });

        /*Outras Funções */
        function controlerFields(pSelect, pFldName) {
            document.getElementById(pFldName).disabled = pSelect;
        }

        function blockAllFields() {
            controlerFields(true, 'IdProject');
            controlerFields(true, 'IdSolution');
            controlerFields(true, 'HasSqlScripts');
            controlerFields(true, 'IdDtbase');

        }

        function showDivHasChecked(phasChecked, pdivName) {
            var stats = 'none';
            if (phasChecked == true) {
                stats = 'block';
            }
            document.getElementById(pdivName).style.display = stats;
        }

        /*Changes Açtions*/

        function getQuerys() {

        }


        //function getQuerys() {
        //    console.log("entrou");
        //    var fileUpload = $("#File").get(0);
        //    var files = fileUpload.files;

        //    var data = new FormData();

        //    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        //        data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        //    }
        //    console.log("send");

        //    $.ajax({
        //        url: "/Package/UploadQuerys",
        //        method: 'post',
        //        data: new FormData($('#File')[0]),
        //        cache: false,
        //        contentType: false,
        //        processData: false,
        //        success: function (result) {
        //            console.log(result);
        //        }
        //    });
        //    //var pIdProject;


        //    //$.ajax({
        //    //    async: true,
        //    //    "url": "/Package/UploadQuerys",
        //    //    "type": "POST",
        //    //    data: data,

        //    //    //success: function (message) {

        //    //    //    alert(message);

        //    //    //},

        //    //    //error: function () {

        //    //    //    alert("There was error uploading files!");

        //    //    //}
        //    //    //data: { _pFiles: data },
        //    //})


        //    //$.ajax({

        //    //    type: "POST",
        //    //    url: "Demo_02/Demo/UploadFilesAjax",
        //    //    contentType: false,
        //    //    processData: false,
        //    //    data: data,
        //    //    success: function (message) {

        //    //        alert(message);

        //    //    },

        //    //    error: function () {

        //    //        alert("There was error uploading files!");

        //    //    }




        //    //$.ajax({
        //    //    async: true,
        //    //    "url": "/Package/UploadQuerys",
        //    //    "type": "POST",
        //    //    data: { _pFiles: teste },
        //    //})
        //        //.done(function (msg) {
        //        //    if (msg.status.includes("nok")) {
        //        //        let results = "Ocorreram erros ao buscar os registros!";

        //        //        if (msg.mesage != undefined && msg.mesage != '') {
        //        //            results = msg.mesage;
        //        //        }

        //        //        toast("Atenção", results, "error");
        //        //        console.log(msg.error);
        //        //    } else {
        //        //        if (msg.partialView != undefined && msg.partialView != '') {
        //        //            $("#divGetQuerys").html(msg.partialView);

        //        //            //if (pIdProject != "" && pIdProject != undefined) {
        //        //            //    $("#pIdProject").val(pIdProject);
        //        //            //}
        //        //        }
        //        //    }
        //        //})
        //        //.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
        //        //    console.log(`${textStatus} - ${msg} - ${jqXHR}`);
        //        //});

        //}

        function getProjectsByEps(pIdEps) {
            var pIdProject;
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                "url": "/Package/GetProjectsByEps",
                "type": "GET",
                data: { pIdEps: pIdEps },
            })
                .done(function (msg) {
                    if (msg.status.includes("nok")) {
                        let results = "Ocorreram erros ao buscar os registros!";

                        if (msg.mesage != undefined && msg.mesage != '') {
                            results = msg.mesage;
                        }

                        toast("Atenção", results, "error");
                        console.log(msg.error);
                    } else {
                        if (msg.partialView != undefined && msg.partialView != '') {
                            $("#divGetProjectsByEps").html(msg.partialView);

                            if (pIdProject != "" && pIdProject != undefined) {
                                $("#pIdProject").val(pIdProject);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
                    console.log(`${textStatus} - ${msg} - ${jqXHR}`);
                });

        }

        function getSolutionsByProject(pIdProject) {
            var pIdSolution;
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                "url": "/Package/GetSolutionsByProject",
                "type": "GET",
                data: { pIdProject: pIdProject },
            })
                .done(function (msg) {
                    if (msg.status.includes("nok")) {
                        let results = "Ocorreram erros ao buscar os registros!";

                        if (msg.mesage != undefined && msg.mesage != '') {
                            results = msg.mesage;
                        }

                        toast("Atenção", results, "error");
                        console.log(msg.error);
                    } else {
                        if (msg.partialView != undefined && msg.partialView != '') {
                            $("#divGetSolutionsByProject").html(msg.partialView);

                            if (pIdSolution != "" && pIdSolution != undefined) {
                                $("#pIdSolution").val(pIdSolution);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
                    console.log(`${textStatus} - ${msg} - ${jqXHR}`);
                });
        }

        function getDatabasesBySolution(pIdSolution) {
            var pIdDtbase;
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                "url": "/Package/GetDatabasesBySolution",
                "type": "GET",
                data: { pIdSolution: pIdSolution },
            })
                .done(function (msg) {
                    if (msg.status.includes("nok")) {
                        let results = "Ocorreram erros ao buscar os registros!";

                        if (msg.mesage != undefined && msg.mesage != '') {
                            results = msg.mesage;
                        }

                        toast("Atenção", results, "error");
                        console.log(msg.error);
                    } else {
                        if (msg.partialView != undefined && msg.partialView != '') {
                            $("#divGetDatabasesBySolution").html(msg.partialView);

                            if (pIdDtbase != "" && pIdDtbase != undefined) {
                                $("#pIdDtbase").val(pIdDtbase);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
                    console.log(`${textStatus} - ${msg} - ${jqXHR}`);
                });
        }



    </script>

}
```

Comment: This is not C code. Please review your tags.

Comment: Wouldn't BeginForm and Action Result always expect to return a view? Have you tried using Ajax.BeginForm? You can update parts of your view from the success of Ajax.BeginForm